# Why am I getting Unexpected end of JSON input in my createComment API function in Next.js app?

Tags: next.js, sanity

When I try to post a comment on my blog to Sanity database nothing shows up.  And when I go to the /api/createComment route this pulls up in the browser:

[image]

Here's the code for createComment endpoint:

```
 import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'
  import   sanityClient   from '@sanity/client'

  const config = {
    dataset: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_DATASET,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
    useCdn: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
    token: process.env.SANITY_API_TOKEN,
   };

  const client = sanityClient(config);



  export default async function createComment(
     req: NextApiRequest,
     res: NextApiResponse
  ) {
        const { _id, name, email, comment } = req.body;


        try {
            await client.create({
                 _type: comment,
                 post: {
                 _type: 'reference',
                 _ref: _id
                },
                 name,
                 email,
                 comment
                });
           } catch(err) {
           return res.status(500).json({ message: 'Couldnt submit 
        comment', err});
       }
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log('Comment submitted');  
    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Comment submitted' });
  }
```

So I console.log(req.body) inside the api function and everything appears just fine in the browser like so:

[image]

This is what the submit handler looks like in the page.tsx:

```
 const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = async (data) => {
  await fetch('/api/createComment', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
  }).then(() => {
      console.log(data);
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
  })
```

So if req.body is populating in the browser console then why am I getting an Unexpected end of JSON input?  Wouldn't that imply that req.body is not populated with anything?

Comment: you don't need to parse the `req.body`,  if you take a close look it's already a JS object.

Comment: So what would be a better alternative for my destructured object to initialize to?  const { _id, name, email, comment } = ????

Comment: did you try `const { _id, name, email, comment } = req.body` ?

Comment: interesting.  I did that and it actually ran through the entire function and now it's throwing this error: "err":{"response":{"body":{"error":{"description":"the mutation(s) failed: Invalid value: Document type is missing in document \

Comment: so the req.body is indeed logging to the browser console so it's receiving the info but it's also showing a POST 500 error which means it's not posting to Sanity.

Comment: can you edit your post with the code of `createComment` api route?

Comment: so it's flagging an error in the submit handler in the index:

Comment: const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = async (data) => {
      await fetch('/api/createComment', {
          method: 'POST',

Comment: yes.  i will do that.

Comment: can you put this `res.status(200).json({ message: 'Comment submitted' });` inside `try` ?

Comment: I did that and it's still throwing the POST 500 error.  And when I go to the exact line in the code next to await fetch() it says 'Failed to load resource'.

Comment: can you post the code of the submit function?

Comment: const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = async (data) => {
      await fetch('/api/createComment', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(() => {
          console.log(data);
      }).catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
      })
  }

Comment: sorry.  I updated the post so you can see it on there for better readability.

Comment: can you try to add headers to your request: `headers:{
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  } `  and see if it works, one thing though, it's better to not combine `await` with `then`,  use `try catch` and one more thing, avoid using error code 500 at all costs, just to make sure that the error is thrown by the server and not the `catch` statement.

Comment: Ok so i added the headers and got rid of .then chain and did a try catch like so:

Comment: const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<IFormInput> = async (data) => {
      await fetch('/api/createComment', {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(data)
      });

      try {
          console.log(data);
      } catch {
          console.log("Couldn't submit comment.");
      }
  }

Comment: and it's still throwing the same error.

Comment: Dear OP, I am reviewer, please edit your question and place `code` in code blocks properly, there a `}` at the end which is outside the code block.

Comment: The GET request you make when looking at the endpoint in the browser is not the same as the POST request you make with Ajax. The GET request has no body, so the server errors with unexpected end of JSON as the body ends immediately without containing any JSON. To debug the request body for the Ajax request you need to use the Network tab of the browser's developer tools. Make sure you look at the payload and the Content-Type *request* header.